# 502 Bad Gateway nginx and ASP.NET Core 3.1 when upload big file

Tags: c#, nginx, .net-core

I've hosted website on linux server (Ubuntu) with .net core sdk installed alongside with nginx

the nginx default configuration (located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` for my website

```
server {
        server_name   mywebsite.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5902;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_connect_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_send_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
                proxy_buffer_size 64k;
                proxy_buffers 16 32k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        }
}
```

and main nginx config (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`):

```
http
{
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
  client_max_body_size 1000M;
  proxy_read_timeout 600;
  proxy_connect_timeout 600;
  proxy_send_timeout 600;

  ...
}
```

When upload 300 MB of file, seems I got 502 error and it crash.

I don't know why it happens

In `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddRazorPages();
...
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
  x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
  x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
});
```

and in controller

```
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[Route("/api/info")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DetectInfo(IFormFile file)
{
            if (file == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            string info = await file.ReadFormFileAsync();
            return Ok(Process(info));
}
```

where `ReadFormFileAsync`

```
public static async Task<string> ReadFormFileAsync(this IFormFile file)
{
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult((string)null);
            }

            using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(bufferedStream))
                {
                    return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                }
            }
}
```

How to fix 502 error ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar that much with ASP.NET and how upload streams should be handled, but a "502" error from Nginx certainly means that the upload process is being terminated from your ASP.NET application and the Nginx simply says that it lost connection with the backend ( in your case it's the ASP.NET I believe ). Therefore, I would highly recommend you make sure that you are correctly using the upload methods for ASP.NET or check the logs of it.